# Make ui-select as required field

Tags: angularjs, ui-select, angular-ui-select

`ng-required="true"` and only required tags or not working with ui-select, this is a long standing bug and I think it is not solved yet.

`%ui-select(ng-model="obj.prop" required)
%ui-select(ng-model="obj.prop" ng-required="true")`

above lines don't work.These lines should workd like `%input.form-control(ng-model="obj.prop" ng-required="true" type="text")`

I want to make ui-select as required field, If this is really a bug then is there an alternate way ??

These lines let the form to be submit even nothing is selected and don't make it as required

Comment: you can check on form submit, that ui-select model shouldn't be empty.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, because I set the `ng-model` value initially to `{}`. When I  set it to null it worked.